# Why is 1 kilobit being equal to 1000 bits is not consistent with other unit conversions?

Tags: byte, bit

1 kilobit being equal to 1000 bits is not consistent with other conversion. Why?

1 byte is equal to 8 bit
1 kilobyte is equal to 8 kbit

1 kilobyte is equal to 1024 byte
So if you convert both bytes into bits, 1 kilobit should also be equal to 1024 bit. But the conversion for 1 kilobit is 1000 bit. Why is there an inconsistency? Is 1 kilobit being equal to 1000 bits correct?

Answer (score 0):

Kilo is based on 10, the prefix for powers of 2 are kibi, mebi, etc. But everybody says kilo, a bad habbit.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte
https://ozanerhansha.medium.com/kilobytes-vs-kibibytes-d77eb2ff6c2a